# Fire event on specific virtual page view

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm very new to GTM, but have managed to get virtual page views working for popups that are loaded via ajax and I'm slowly getting the hang of it.

What I'm now trying to do is create a trigger that fires on a specific page view *(e.g. "/thanks")*. Ordinarily this would be trivial using a page view event, but because the page in question only gets *virtual* page views, this does not fire when viewed via this ajax loaded content.

For reference, this is how I set up the virtual page view;

On the relevant template file I have the following javascript (and dynamic php variables);

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'VirtualPageview',
    'virtualPageURL': '/".$page->page_uri."',
    'virtualPageTitle': '$node_data[title]'
});
```

- I have two data layer variables as above `virtualPageURL` and `virtualPageTitle`,
- A custom event trigger that fires on `VirtualPageview`,
- and a Tag set to fire on `VirtualPageview` that passed the two custom variables with it;

[image]

How can I get this virtual page view to fire other page view events in GTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself after a load of trial and error. Turns out it wasn't too complicated after all. Here's what I did;

**1. Duplicated the virtual page trigger and amend**

After copying the virtual page trigger, I added another condition for the `virtualPageURL` to match a url that I specified.
[image]

Then I created a new analytics tag with an event **Track Type**. Clicked on **More** in the **Fire On** section and selected my newly created trigger.

Then hey presto, it fires the trigger when on that specific page when triggered via a virtual page view.